# Best way to organize tests in RSpec that have a Combinations of factor

Tags: ruby, csv, rspec

I am creating some tests that have a variety of inputs. I am testing a purchasing website with new and returning user types, different products, promotion codes, payment options. I felt like this was a data-driven test set, probably calling for a csv or spreadsheet format of the test inputs.

I have been using rspec which was perfect for the last test set I created.

I would like to have consistent result formats. I am stuck on how to use data tables with RSpec. Has anybody used RSpec with a table of test inputs?

Thanks in advance for a direct solution or sound advice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're going to use a table, I would define it in-line within the test file something like...

```
[
  %w( abc  123  def  ),
  %w( wxyz 9876 ab   ),
  %w( mn   10   pqrs )
].each do |a,b,c|
  describe "Given inputs #{a} and #{b}" do
    it "returns #{c}" do
      Something.whatever(a,b).should == c
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is pretty much what I am looking for except that I will do the table on the 'it "should do whatever" do' part. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

One idiomatic approach would be to use RSpec [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) with parameters. I'm going to assume that each table row corresponds to a distinct test case, and the columns break-down the variables involved.

As an example, suppose you have some code that calculates the price of a car based on it's configuration. Say we have a class `Car` and we want to test that the `price` method conforms to the manufacturer's suggested retail price (MSRP).

We might be required to test the following combinations:

```
Doors | Color | Interior | MSRP
--------------------------------
4     | Blue  | Cloth    | $X
2     | Red   | Leather  | $Y
```

Let's create a shared example that captures this information and tests for the correct behavior.

```
RSpec.shared_examples "msrp" do |doors, color, interior, msrp|
  context "with #{doors} doors, #{color}, #{interior}" do
    subject { Car.new(doors, color, interior).price }
    it { should eq(msrp) }
  end
end
```

Having written this shared example, we can then succinctly test multiple configurations without the burden of code duplication.

```
RSpec.describe Car do
  describe "#price" do
    it_should_behave_like "msrp", 4, "Blue", "Cloth", X
    it_should_behave_like "msrp", 2, "Red", "Leather", Y
  end
end
```

When we run this spec, the output should be of the form:

```
Car
  #price
    it should behave like msrp
      when 4 doors, Blue, Cloth
        should equal X
      when 2 doors, Red, Leather
        should equal Y
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user_types = ['rich', 'poor']
products = ['apples', 'bananas']
promo_codes = [123, 234]
results = [12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89].to_enum
test_combis = user_types.product(products, promo_codes)

test_combis.each do |ut, p, pc|
  puts "testing #{ut}, #{p} and #{pc} should == #{results.next}"
end
```

Output:

```
testing rich, apples and 123 should == 12
testing rich, apples and 234 should == 23
testing rich, bananas and 123 should == 34
testing rich, bananas and 234 should == 45
testing poor, apples and 123 should == 56
testing poor, apples and 234 should == 67
testing poor, bananas and 123 should == 78
testing poor, bananas and 234 should == 89
```